# Can we derive message From CRC

Tags: compression, crc

I have a 100Bytes of data and calculated CRC-64 on the same.
I have the CRC and 4 bytes of original data available (the 4 bytes are the last or first 4 bytes of data and we can choose it)
Is it possible to rebuild the data?

Comment: The data can't be rebuilt. You could set the unknown data to all zeroes except for 8 bytes and set the values of those 8 bytes to end up with a CRC-64 of zero.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You would be able to do so only if the number of unknown bytes was less than or equal to the number of bytes in the CRC (which is eight). You have 96 unknown bytes.